How does AKS / FLUX install a local helm chart?
I've recently been looking into GITOPS & FLUX and am struggling to figure out how to install a local HELM chart.
My setup is AKS, using the GITOPS/FLUX add-in and I'm doing the configuration via the portal to keep it simple.
It works using kustomization.yaml & k8s manifests, but HELM is beating me ‍♂️
This is my basic folder structure, and it's here also if it's easier to visualise https://github.com/rhod3rz/temp.
+---1-kustomize
|   +---base
|   |       kustomization.yaml
|   |       pod.yaml
|   |
|   \---overlays
|       +---dev
|       |       kustomization.yaml
|       |
|       \---prd
|               kustomization.yaml
|
\---2-helm
    |   Chart.yaml
    |   values.yaml
    |
    \---charts
        \---app1
            |   Chart.yaml
            |
            \---templates
                    pod.yaml

If I create a FLUX kustomization pointing at 1-kustomize/overlays/dev all is good.
If I create a FLUX kustomization pointing at 2-helm, I thought it would install the chart but it just errors:

failed to decode Kubernetes YAML from /tmp/kustomization-3631900086/2-helm/Chart.yaml: missing kind in object {{v2 } {{ } map[] map[]}}

I've done a lot of searching & found info and got it working for hosted helm charts, just not local.
Any ideas anyone? 

You should be using flux helmrelease instead of flux kustomization. Sounds like you're trying to point kustomization to helm which is not how it's supposed to be.

Taledor's suggestion is accurate. The error failed to decode Kubernetes YAML from /tmp/kustomization-3631900086/2-helm/Chart.yaml: missing kind in object occurred because a Kustomization was mistakenly pointed at a directory containing a Helm chart, which it can't handle as it expects standard Kubernetes YAML files.
How to fix it?
The correct approach involves creating a HelmRelease resource that specifies how to install the Helm chart from your repository. This resource tells Flux where to find the Helm chart within your Git repository, any configurations to apply from the values.yaml, and the synchronization details.
Make sure that your HelmRelease YAML points to the correct directory within your Git repository where your Chart.yaml is located. Update the path in the chart.spec.chart field if necessary. For example, if your Helm chart is located under charts/myapp/
Example
apiVersion: helm.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v2beta1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: myapp-release
  namespace: default
spec:
  interval: 1m
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: ./charts/myapp
      sourceRef:
        kind: GitRepository
        name: flux-helm-aks
        namespace: flux-system
  values:
    replicaCount: 1


Commit and push the HelmRelease YAML to your Git repository

Done.
Flux will automatically pick up changes from your Git repository and apply them based on the HelmRelease configuration.
Verify installation, after ensuring all configurations are correct and pushed
kubectl get helmrelease -n default


Helmrelease works excellently for all cases except a Kubernetes Job. The Job deployment will fail because it is an immutable object in Kubernetes. So, in this case, Kustomization is the only option.
